# Java construtor com matriz

Tags: java, matriz, construtor

estou aprendendo sobre construtores em java porém travei no exercício da faculdade que me pareceu simples, a proposta é criar uma classe construtor com uma matriz, e chamá-la numa outra classe para atribular os valores a matriz:

Construtor:

```
public class Populacao {

    public void atualizarPopulacao(int i, int j, int populacao){
        if (i>=0 && i<4 && j>=0 && j<5 && populacao > 0)
            pop[i][j] = populacao;
        }

  }
```

Classe principal:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Administracao {

    public static void main(String p[]) {

        Populacao pop = new Populacao();

         int i,j;
         int n;

         for (i=0; i<4; i++){
             for(j=0; j<5; j++){
                 n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Populacão: " + String.valueOf(i+1) + "\nEstado: " + String.valueOf(j+1)));

                 pop.atualizarPopulacao(i, j, n);

             }
         }



    }

}
```

Porém recebo o erro:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Alguém pode me ajudar a atribuir os valores à matriz chamando o construtor?

Comment: O problema é que você precisa instanciar a matriz. Exemplo: `pop = new int[4][5]`

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro vamos ao porque você pode esta recebendo o `NullPointerException`:

Acredito que existe algum código faltando no que você postou, caso contrário o código nem compilaria, porém o que pode estar causando esse erro é a não inicialização da sua variável `pop` utilizada dentro da seu método `atualizarPopulacao`.

Se você tenta atribuir um valor a sua variável `pop[i][j] = populacao;` mas ela não foi inicializada previamente, um `NullPointerException` irá estourar.

Segue abaixo um código que eu acredito que funcionaria para o seu caso. Não pude testar o código pois não tenho Java nessa máquina.

**Classe Populacao:**

```
public class Populacao{
    private Integer[][] matriz; //Declaração da variavel

    /* Construtor da classe Populacao, recebe o numero de cidades e estados
       e cria uma matriz com as dimensões numero de cidades por numero de estados */
    public Populacao(int numeroCidades, int numeroEstados){
        this.matriz = new Integer[numeroCidades][numeroEstados]; //Inicializacao da variavel
    }

    //Atualiza a populacao da cidade no estado.
    public void atualizaPopulacao(int cidade, int estado, Integer populacao){
        this.matriz[cidade][estado] = populacao;
    }

    public int getNumeroCidades(){
        return this.matriz.length;
    }

    public int getNumeroEstados(){
        return this.matriz[0].length;
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Integer numeroHabitantes;
    int numeroCidades = 4;
    int numeroEstados = 3;
    Populacao populacao = new Populacao(numeroCidades, numeroEstados);

    for(int i=0; i < populacao.getNumeroCidades(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j < populacao.getNumeroEstados(); j++){
            numeroHabitantes = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Populacão: " + String.valueOf(i+1) + "\nEstado: " + String.valueOf(j+1)));
            populacao.atualizaPopulacao(i, j, numeroHabitantes);  
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, exatamente o que precisava, aprimorei pra meu exercícios, funcionou e aprendi.

Comment: @JohnnyBastos se as duas respostas te ajudaram, esolha aquela que você achs que melhor se adequa ao seu problema e marque como a solucao

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro você tem que ver que um construtor tem que ter exatamente o mesmo nome da classe o que não ocorre no seu código e é um dos fatores que pode estar gerando o erro.
Outro ponto é o uso do construtor ocorre quando você ao instancia o objeto tem que passar os atributos por parâmetro:

E.x.: essa classe Paciente eu criei um construtor que recebe dois valores por parâmetro.

```
public class Paciente {

    float peso;
    double altura;

    public Paciente(float peso, double altura) {
        this.peso = peso;
        this.altura = altura;
    }
}
```

quando eu instanciar esta classe na classe de execução eu já tenho que passar os argumentos para criar o objeto.

e.x.:

```
public class Principal {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Paciente p1 = new Paciente(100f, 1.75);
        Paciente p2 = new Paciente(78f, 1.80);
        Paciente p3 = new Paciente(130f, 1.85);
    }
}
```

Se eu não passar algum argumento conforme o padrão do construtor ocorrerá erro, então repare que na instancia do objeto entre parenteses há os dois argumentos conforme cada tipo que serão recebidos pelo construtor.

Logo no seu caso para que você consiga criar seu objeto você tem que seguir essas regras de criação de construtor, gerar a matriz antes da criação do objeto e não esquecer de declarar na assinatura do construtor o tipo de parâmetro que este deve recebe.

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito!